# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. while build apk

Tags: android

I know that there is so many question regarding this, but I have tried all solution from StackOverflow but still I did not resolve this issue

my app level build.gradle files is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }




    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aple.gole.video"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "a1bdfc88-fffb-4283-9c45-8a15b3bbd3a2",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7.7'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.2'

    compile ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
    }
    compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I started to get this issue when I used this

```
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but it required for firebase

my project level build.gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

From External Library I have found different version of Google Play Service

Might be that will crate problem, let me share you screenshot

[please click here to check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dninx.png)

but now problem is why there is different version of Google Play Service, One is **Play Service iid 10.0.1** and other one is **play service task 11.0.2**
,How to make it same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have found that you

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
```

is using

```
    google-play-service lib 11.0.2
```

You can do this

```
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
```

so it will use

```
 google-play-service lib 10.0.1
```

it will work, I have tested

Comment: Oh thanks Amit, let me check if it is possible or not